# ASP.net URL problem: Website Domain not appearing on front of URLs

Tags: asp.net, iis

I create a menu structure from a compiled class that returns an unordered list with ~/ menu options. On my localhost, they show up as http://localhost:port/applicationpath/Default.aspx

I actually have to pass the Application Path to the function to prefix the URLs. The problem, however, is that we moved the application to our development server, and now the URLS show up as:

http://default.aspx/?id=1
http://folder/default.aspx

The website domain doesn't seem to be displaying. Anyone have any clue? Is this an IIS issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a getRootURL() function within my javascript to do the job.